# Twitter bootstrap span class on buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very fond of the twitter bootstrap css/less framework, but recently I have found a slight issue.

When I put `.spanX` on a button they do not become the same width as a div.

Se this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8zu9/1/) to see an example of what I mean. In the picture below, both are `.span4`.

[image: They are both .span4 but different width]

Am I using the span class wrong, or is this maybe a bug?

---

Edit:

I use chrome 23.0.1271.64 on mac osx the-new-cat.

Comment: they are of the same width as I see them.

Comment: Maybe your question needs to be more specific by sharing which browser you're seeing this behavior in. It looks fine to me in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.alert` adds `padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px;` which is responsible for the size difference either overwrite it or remove the .alert class

Comment: This seems to be the issue! Thank you! I tried to add .alert on the button to compensate, but that did not work. At least I know the issue now, so I should be able to come up with something :)

Answer (score 6):

Twitter Bootstrap offers the BLOCK-LEVEL button class for that purpose.

Look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons - there'll find an example for using the .btn-block class in conjunction with `<button>`.

Basically, you may have to wrap your `<button>` in a `<div>`, like so:

```
<div class="span12">
    <button class="btn btn-block">my wide button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I did not know back then how to enter `<html>` tags - fixed my answer so that the `<html>` show up (:

Answer (score 0):

They are the same width as i can see even after resizing the browser window..

You may clear your browser cache to check how it works and also try from a different browser from the current one that you are using..

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, you can see this articles:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3824

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/5198